# Camelot-py does not work in loops but works for an individual file

Tags: python-3.x, automation

I am currently working on an automation project for a company, and one of the tasks require that I loop through a directory and convert all the pdf files into a CSV file. I am using the `camelot-py` library (which has been better than the others I have tried). When I apply the code below to a single file, it works just fine; however, I wish to make it loop through all pdf files in the directory. I get the following error with the code below:

"OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument"

```
import camelot
import csv
import pandas as pd 
import os

directoryPath = r'Z:\testDirectory'
os.chdir(directoryPath)
print(os.listdir())
folderList = os.listdir(directoryPath)
for folders, sub_folders, file in os.walk(directoryPath):  
    for name in file:
        if name.endswith(".pdf"):
            filename = os.path.join(folders,name)
            print(filename)
            print(name)
            tables = camelot.read_pdf(filename, flavor = 'stream', columns= ['72,73,150,327,442,520,566,606,683'])
            tables = tables[0].df
            print(tables[0].parsing_report)       
            tables.to_csv('foo2.csv')
```

I expect all files to be converted to '.csv' files but I get the error 'OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument'. My error appears to be from line 16.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if you have the same problem, but in my case I made a really stupid mistake of not putting the files in the correct directory. I was getting the same error but once I found out the problem, script works within a regular for loop.

Instead of the to methods, I am using the bulk export to export the results in sql, but that should not be a problem.